# Iterating simultaneously/List comprehension issue (in UDF to obtain Merge Report in Pandas)

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge, pandas, stata

Stata users will know that when merging data a `_merge` variable is produced that indicates by `_merge` being 1 that the `merge` was successful for that observation, by 2 that the observation is in the master dataset only, or by 3  that the observation is in the using dataset only. I am trying to re-create this in pandas by writing my own function. I have the following workings:

```
def MergeReport(DF1, DF2, keys, HOW = 'outer'):

    if len(keys) == 1:
        KeysDF1 = set(DF1[keys[0]])
        KeysDF2 = set(DF2[keys[0]])
        MasterError = list(KeysDF1.difference(KeysDF2))
        UsingError = list(KeysDF2.difference(KeysDF1))
        MG = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on = keys, how = HOW)
        MG['_merge'] = None

        for row in MG.index:
            if MG[keys[0]][row] in MasterError:
                MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_2"
            elif MG[keys[0]][row] in UsingError:
                MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_3"
            else:
                MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_1"

        return MG       

    else:
        KeysDF1 = set(zip(DF1[keys[0]], DF1[keys[1]]))      
        KeysDF2 = set(zip(DF2[keys[0]], DF2[keys[1]]))          
        MasterError = list(KeysDF1.difference(KeysDF2)) 
        UsingError = list(KeysDF2.difference(KeysDF1))
        MG = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on = keys, how = HOW)
        MG['_merge'] = None

        for row in MG.index:
            if tuple([MG[keys[0]][row], MG[keys[1]][row]]) in MasterError:
                MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_2"
            elif tuple([MG[keys[0]][row], MG[keys[1]][row]]) in UsingError:
                MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_3"
            else:
                MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_1"

        return MG
```

The arguments are DataFrame1, DataFrame2, List of 'Keys' (i.e. columns to merge on) and an optional argument HOW which is passed to the pd.merge argument how = HOW. Eventually the arguments will be extended to all of those within the pd.merge function.

My problem is I think obvious: I can not figure out how to write the code such that it can accept a list of keys of any length. My problem happens here:

```
KeysDF1 = set(zip(DF1[keys[0]], DF1[keys[1]]))      
KeysDF2 = set(zip(DF2[keys[0]], DF2[keys[1]]))
```

I cannot figure out how to write this such that I can iterate through a list of keys of any length. In particular I tried list comprehension:

```
KeysDF1 =   set(zip(tuple([DF1[keys[x]] for x in range(len(keys))])))
```

but that did not work because "Series objects are mutable, they cannot be hashed".
I think I will find similar problems at this point in the code as well:

```
if tuple([MG[keys[0]][row], MG[keys[1]][row]]) in MasterError:
    MG['_merge'][row] = "merge_2"
```

EDIT: AT THE SUGGESTION OF ANOTHER USER I AM POSTING AN ALTERNATIVE MEANS OF ACHIEVING THE SAME GOAL. I'M NOT SUGGESTING THIS AS A SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM ITSELF, MERELY A METHOD THAT AVOIDS THE ISSUE:

```
def MergeReport(DF1, DF2, how = 'inner', on = None, left_on = None, right_on = None, \    left_index = False, right_index = False, \sort = False, suffixes = ('_x', '_y'), copy = True):
    DF1['Master'] = 1
    DF2['Using'] = 2

    MDF = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how = how, on = on, left_on = left_on, right_on = right_on, left_index = left_index, right_index = right_index, \
sort = sort, suffixes = suffixes, copy = copy)

    MDF['Master'].fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)
    MDF['Using'].fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)
    MDF['_Merge'] = MDF['Master'] + MDF['Using']
    del MDF['Master']
    del MDF['Using']
    List = ['1_MasterOnly', '2_UsingOnly', '3_Matched']
    LIST = [List[int(MDF['_Merge'][row] - 1)] for row in MDF.index]
    MDF['_Merge'] = np.array(LIST)
    return MDF
```

Comment: A colleague just pointed out that a much easier way to do this would to be to create a column in DF1 with all values equal to 1, and a variable in DF2 with all values equal to 2, and then in the merged data frame to create a _merge variable equal to the sum of those two variables, this would indicate where the problems were i.e. 1 in master only, 2 in using only and 3 success.... Much easier I guess, but I still wonder what the solutio to the above might be?

Comment: Feel free to post your practical solution as an answer.

Comment: How do I do that? Replying to my own question?

Comment: I'm not sure I have the answer to my question, I only have an alternative solution

Comment: It'll be more useful to others than the nothing that is currently here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly, but the generalization of

```
KeysDF1 = set(zip(DF1[keys[0]], DF1[keys[1]]))
```

doesn't seem to me

```
KeysDF1 =   set(zip(tuple([DF1[keys[x]] for x in range(len(keys))])))
```

but rather

```
KeysDF1 =   set(zip(*tuple([DF1[keys[x]] for x in range(len(keys))])))
```

or simply

```
KeysDF1 =   set(zip(*[DF1[keys[x]] for x in range(len(keys))]))
```